# Subclass QLineEdit and add label underneath

Tags: python, pyside

Is it possible to subclass qlineedit and place a qlabel under it? Or do I have to creat Qwidget and add line edit and label to a layout in order to get propery sizing?

I was trying to subclass the qlineedit so I could avoid having to rewrite all the qlineedit methods. I like the methods being directly accessible when aubclassing qlineedit.

To clarify I'm trying to place the label vertically below the line at it which would be on the Y position

[image]

```
class Example(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    '''
    List item representing a Job 
    '''
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Example, self).__init__(parent)

        # properties
        self.uiTitle = QtWidgets.QLineEdit()
        self.uiTitle.setStyleSheet('font-size:14px; font-weight:bold; color:white;')

        self.subtitle = QtWidgets.QLabel('Here is a hint...')
        self.subtitle.setStyleSheet('font-size:11px;')

        self.mainLayout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self)
        self.mainLayout.addWidget(self.uiTitle)
        self.mainLayout.addWidget(self.subtitle)


def main():
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = Example()
    ex.show()
    app.exec_()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    pass
    main()
```

Comment: By "under" do you mean "vertically below" (with an y offset) or literally (with a z offset)?

Comment: I mean vertically under the lineedit

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution could be to change the contents margins of the QLineEdit and add a QLabel that is a direct child of it. Note that you cannot use a layout for the line edit, otherwise it will resize the whole line edit field.

```
class LineEditLabel(QtWidgets.QLineEdit):
    _spacing = 14
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self._baseHeight = self.sizeHint().height()
        self.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, self.fontMetrics().height() + self._spacing)
        self._label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self)

    @QtCore.pyqtProperty(str)
    def labelText(self):
        return self._label.text()

    @labelText.setter
    def labelText(self, text):
        self._label.setText(text)
        self.updateLabelRect()

    def setLabelText(self, text):
        self.labelText = text

    def updateLabelRect(self):
        self.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 
            self.fontMetrics().boundingRect(self._label.text()).height() + self._spacing)
        rect = self._label.rect()
        rect.setWidth(self.width())
        rect.moveBottom(self.height())
        self._label.setGeometry(rect)

    def resizeEvent(self, event):
        super().resizeEvent(event)
        self.updateLabelRect()
```